# Loading .txt into text area - new line not retained in IE

Tags: jquery, textarea, newline, fwrite, jquery-load

I made a simple web app which lets you edit `.txt` files. The `.txt` files are loaded into a `<textarea>` using jQuery-Ajax (in this case, `$.load`). Then, you can click 'save' and the file is saved using PHP `fwrite()`

This all works fine in modern browsers, tested in Chrome and Safari. However, when I tried it in Internet Explorer 8, it failed. The problem is that it doesn't register new lines. `.txt` files that already *had* new lines didn't keep the new lines when `$.load`ed into the `<textarea>`. When the files were saved, they saved *without* the new lines so when opened in a modern browser everything was jumbled up!

IE support is a key part of this web app, and this issue has been with me for a long time... I haven't found any solution yet despite a lot of research.

---

If you want to look at the code, the URL is [www.scriptr.net](http://www.scriptr.net)

But really, the key bit is just:

```
$('p').load('somefile.txt');
var contents = $('p').html();
$('textarea').val(contents);
```

and then when the save button is clicked, the textarea is part of a form submitted to a PHP script which uses `fwrite()`s it.

Comment: Sounds like a line ending issue. Try replacing each occurence of `\n` in the loaded string with `\r\n` and see if it helps.

Comment: Will try, only thing is I don't have access to a Windows computer right now!

Comment: @Hristo lliev '\r\n' does not work in my case